# How to get all inputs to reset on click of the reset form button

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am learning react and react native and trying to build a basic form. I want what is inputted in the inputs to be displayed below. Then on clicking the reset form button have all the inputs reset.

It is only resetting the first input and I can feel myself slowly grasping react but I am stuck on this last part. If someone could tell me how to fix this and explain the reasoning behind it it would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button, InputAccessoryView, TextInput} from 'react-native';


export default function Form() {
  const inputAccessoryViewID = 'uniqueID';
  const initialText='';
  const[text, setText] = useState(initialText);
  const[text2, setText2] = useState(initialText);
  const[text3, setText3] = useState(initialText);
  const[text4, setText4] = useState(initialText);
  const[text5, setText5] = useState(initialText);
  var onPressed = () =>{
    setText(initialText);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.input}>
      <TextInput inputAccessoryViewID={inputAccessoryViewID} onChangeText={setText} value={text} placeholder={'First and Last Name'}/>
      </View>
          <View style={styles.input}>
      <TextInput keyboardType="numeric" inputAccessoryViewID={inputAccessoryViewID} onChangeText={setText2} value={text2} placeholder={'Phone Number'}/>
      </View>
          <View style={styles.input}>
      <TextInput inputAccessoryViewID={inputAccessoryViewID} onChangeText={setText3} value={text3} placeholder={'Program'}/>
      </View>
          <View style={styles.input}>
      <TextInput inputAccessoryViewID={inputAccessoryViewID} onChangeText={setText4} value={text4} placeholder={'Favourite Food'}/>
      </View>
          <View style={styles.input}>
      <TextInput inputAccessoryViewID={inputAccessoryViewID} onChangeText={setText5} value={text5} placeholder={'Hobby'}/>
      </View>
      <InputAccessoryView nativeID={inputAccessoryViewID}>
      <Button
      onPress={() => setText(initialText)}
      title = "Reset Form"
      />
      </InputAccessoryView>
      <Text style={styles.displayText}> 
      {text} 
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.displayText}>
      {text2}
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.displayText}>
      {text3}
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.displayText}>
      {text4}
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.displayText}>
      {text5}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to reset all states in the `onPress`:

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button, InputAccessoryView, TextInput} from 'react-native';


export default function Form() {
  const inputAccessoryViewID = 'uniqueID';
  const initialText='';
  const[text, setText] = useState(initialText);
  const[text2, setText2] = useState(initialText);
  const[text3, setText3] = useState(initialText);
  const[text4, setText4] = useState(initialText);
  const[text5, setText5] = useState(initialText);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.input}>
      <TextInput inputAccessoryViewID={inputAccessoryViewID} onChangeText={setText} value={text} placeholder={'First and Last Name'}/>
      </View>
          <View style={styles.input}>
      <TextInput keyboardType="numeric" inputAccessoryViewID={inputAccessoryViewID} onChangeText={setText2} value={text2} placeholder={'Phone Number'}/>
      </View>
          <View style={styles.input}>
      <TextInput inputAccessoryViewID={inputAccessoryViewID} onChangeText={setText3} value={text3} placeholder={'Program'}/>
      </View>
          <View style={styles.input}>
      <TextInput inputAccessoryViewID={inputAccessoryViewID} onChangeText={setText4} value={text4} placeholder={'Favourite Food'}/>
      </View>
          <View style={styles.input}>
      <TextInput inputAccessoryViewID={inputAccessoryViewID} onChangeText={setText5} value={text5} placeholder={'Hobby'}/>
      </View>
      <InputAccessoryView nativeID={inputAccessoryViewID}>
      <Button
      onPress={() => {
            setText(initialText);
            setText2(initialText);
            setText3(initialText);
            setText4(initialText);
            setText5(initialText);
      }}
      title = "Reset Form"
      />
      </InputAccessoryView>
      <Text style={styles.displayText}> 
      {text} 
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.displayText}>
      {text2}
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.displayText}>
      {text3}
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.displayText}>
      {text4}
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.displayText}>
      {text5}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

This will reset all states to your initial text.

Comment: Awesome thank you, i had tried to do that but wasn't sure how to implement it with in the onPress.

Comment: @user17162404 good to hear! Remember to accept the answer if it's what you're looking for! (There should be a check under the voting buttons)

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your form state tracking and make it easier to reset by using [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) instead of useState. With useReducer your entire form state could live in one place instead of being spread across a dozen different state variables.

If you go this route you can reset the form with a single call to `dispatch(initialState)`.

Psuedocode:

```
const initialState = {
  'First Name': '',
  'Last Name': ''
  'Favorite Food': '',
}

// just merges the "action" into the existing state
const reducer = (state, action) => ({...state, ...action});

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

return (
  <View>
    {
      // create a text input for each key/value in initialState
      Object.entries(initialState).map(([name, value]) => (
        <TextInput
          placeholder={name}
          value={value}
          onChangeText={newValue => dispatch({[name]: newValue})}
        />
      ))
    }
    <Button
      onPress={() => dispatch(initialState)}
      title = "Reset Form"
    />
  </View>
)
```